# ImportError: cannot import name '_get_cpp_backtrace' from 'torch._C'

Tags: pytorch, importerror, torchvision

```
import torchvision

import torchvision.transforms as transforms
```

I ran this code, but following error appeared.

this is the error message

```
ImportError: cannot import name '_get_cpp_backtrace' from 'torch._C' (C:\Users\cgt05\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\_C.cp310-win_amd64.pyd)`
```

What's the problem?
I tried uninstall pytorch and install it again, but the problem was not solved.

I have all of the lastest version of torch, cuda, python.
(torch-> 2.0.0, cuda->12.1 python->3.11)

Answer (score 13):

Are you using a **Jupyter Notebook**? If so, what helped for me was simply **restarting the kernel**. The notebook was able to detect the installed package.

For reference, [this answer](https://github.com/obss/sahi/discussions/781#discussioncomment-4397427) helped me to solve it.

Comment: I'm using Jupyter Notebook, it works for me!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and the way I fixed it was to go to the file path it specified. Then found the file and deleted the `_C.cp310-win_amd64.pyd.c~` which is a "CONDA_TRASH File". Deleting this and re running my file allowed it to run and the error never came up again.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the path in LD_LIBRARY_PATH or PATH ? I had the same error, two python conda paths were conflicting in LD_LIBRARY_PATH and PATH.