# ImportError: cannot import name '_get_cpp_backtrace' from 'torch._C', when installing pytorch on venv in a docker container

Tags: python, linux, pytorch

I'm using the docker container on the image named `nvcr.io/nvidia/pytorch:22.09-py3`.

In the container, I've made a `venv` and installed `torch`.

Since my NVIDIA driver version is 11.8, I've use `pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu118` as a install command.
(I've got from here, https://pytorch.org/)

But it shows me an error below.

```py
Python 3.8.13 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Mar 25 2022, 06:04:10)
[GCC 10.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import torch
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/root/HF/.HF/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/__init__.py", line 1119, in <module>
    from ._tensor import Tensor
  File "/root/HF/.HF/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/_tensor.py", line 12, in <module>
    import torch.utils.hooks as hooks
  File "/root/HF/.HF/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .cpp_backtrace import get_cpp_backtrace
  File "/root/HF/.HF/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/cpp_backtrace.py", line 1, in <module>
    from torch._C import _get_cpp_backtrace
ImportError: cannot import name '_get_cpp_backtrace' from 'torch._C' (/root/HF/.HF/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/_C.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
```

Is it because there is some naturally bonded torch version to the container?

I can find the torch which is originally installed when not using `venv`.
(I don't think it is the reason personally)

```py
Python 3.8.13 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Mar 25 2022, 06:04:10)
[GCC 10.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import torch
>>> print(torch.__version__)
1.13.0a0+d0d6b1f
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: cannot import name '\_get\_cpp\_backtrace' from 'torch.\_C'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76180804/importerror-cannot-import-name-get-cpp-backtrace-from-torch-c)

Comment: I have tried it before, but none of them works for me.